# How can I identify date columns and format it to YYYY-MM-DD in Python using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, date

I am trying to format the dates in Python using Pandas. Basically, I want to identify all the date columns and convert it to YYYY-MM-DD format, overwrite and save it.

Input:

| ID | NPC_code | Date1 | Date2 | Date3 | Date4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10001 | 10-01-2020 | 11012019 | 27-Jan-18 | 27Jan2016 |
| 2 | 10002 | 11-01-2020 | 11012020 | 28-Jan-18 | 27Jan2017 |
| 3 | 10003 | 12-01-2020 | 11012021 | 29-Jan-18 | 27Jan2018 |
| 4 | 10004 | 13-01-2020 | 11012022 | 30-Jan-18 | 27Jan2019 |
| 5 | 10005 | 14-01-2020 | 11012023 | 31-Jan-18 | 27Jan2020 |

Output:

| ID | NPC_code | Date1 | Date2 | Date3 | Date4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10001 | 2020-01-10 | 2019-01-11 | 2018-01-27 | 2016-01-27 |
| 2 | 10002 | 2020-01-11 | 2020-01-11 | 2018-01-28 | 2016-01-28 |
| 3 | 10003 | 2020-01-12 | 2021-01-11 | 2018-01-29 | 2016-01-29 |
| 4 | 10004 | 2020-01-13 | 2022-01-11 | 2018-01-30 | 2016-01-30 |
| 5 | 10005 | 2020-01-14 | 2023-01-11 | 2018-01-31 | 2016-01-31 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your column is a string, you will need to first use `pd.to_datetime',

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

Then, use .dt datetime accessor with strftime:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':pd.date_range('2017-01-01', periods = 60, freq='D')})

df.Date.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').astype(int)
```

Or use lambda function:

```
df.Date.apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

refer:

1. [strftime-and-strptime-behavior](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)
2. [pd.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)

```py
df['Date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date1, format='%d-%m-%Y')
pd.to_datetime(df.Date2, format='%d%m%Y')
pd.to_datetime(df.Date3, format='%d-%b-%y')
pd.to_datetime(df.Date4, format='%d%b%Y')
```

convert to string format:

```
pd.to_datetime(df.Date1, format='%d-%m-%Y').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```